# Quoi que vs quoique (prononciation)

Tags: prononciation

> Je commence à progresser quoique le français soit une langue
>   difficile.
>
> Quoi que je fasse il me reste encore trop de fautes dans mes
>   exercices.

La prononciation de quoique (conjonction de subordination) et quoi que (pronom relatif) est-elle la même ? Quoi que a-t-il un hiatus?

Ibid. pour le couple quel que (quelle que, quels que, quelles que) et quelque(s).

Comment: Je suis français et je prononce Quoi que et Quoique de la même manière. Cependant je ne prononce pas Quel que et Quelques de la même façon. Le premier sonne plus Quel qu-E et le deuxième plus Quelk sans prononcer le "e"

Comment: Même observation que @TimLepage même si personnellement je prononce "quel que" et "quelque" de la même manière.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les prononciations de *quoique* et *quoi que* sont le plus souvent si ce n'est toujours indiscernables à l'oral.

La seule variation notable est la prononciation ou l'élision du e final, mais les règles qui s'appliquent aux deux cas sont très proches.

Quand un mot commençant par une consonne suit, le *e* est optionnel dans la langue parlée :

> Quoi que je fasse, je pense à toi.   /kwakə ʒə fas/ ou /kwakʒəfas/ (Quoi qu'je fasse) ou /kwakʒfas/ (Quoi qu'j'fasse).
>
> Quoique je fasse des efforts pour t'oublier, je pense à toi. (Quoi qu'je fasse des efforts)

*Quoique* étant d'un registre plus soutenu que *quoi que* (qui l'est déjà pas mal), l'élision sera probablement plus rare dans le deuxième cas et la double élision (quoiqu'j'fasse) encore plus rare .

Devant une voyelle , le *e* de *quoi que* s'élide toujours à l'écrit comme à l'oral alors que celui de *quoique* ne s'élide à l'écrit que dans un nombre de cas limités (il, elle, on, un, en, à, avec, aussi, aucun et enfin) :

> Quoi qu'il mange, il ne grossit pas.
>
> Quoiqu'il mange sans arrêt, il ne grossit pas.

On est donc censé écrire :

> Quoique immobile, cette voiture consomme de l'essence.

mais on lit quand même parfois *quoiqu'immobile*.

En pratique, la phrase utilisée permet de déterminer s'il s'agit de la conjonction *quoique* ou de la locution *quoi que*.

On peut faire sensiblement les mêmes observations  à propos de *quel que* et *quelque*, si ce n'est que *quelque* peut jouer plus de rôles grammaticaux que *quoique* et que son *e* final ne s'élide à l'écrit que devant *un* (quelqu'un).

Answer (score 2):

Mes prononciations de «quel.le.s que» et «quelques» sont très légèrement différentes, mais je pense qu’elles le sont à cause de mon expérience de la lecture plutôt que d’une réelle différence de prononciation des gens qui m’entourent. Et il est incertain que je puisse reconnaître à l’écoute l’une prononciation de l’autre. Je perçois probablement plus la différence dans la position de ma bouche et de ma langue qu’avec mes oreilles. Une prononciation identique ne pose aucun problème.

Dans la langue familière par contre on entend «quelques» prononcé «kek», mais ce n’est jamais le cas pour «quel.le.s que».

- Quelquefois ça arrive (registre familier identique)
- Quelques fois par jour (registre familier possible: Queq fois par jour)
- Quelque chose de bien (registre familier possible: Queq chose de bien)
- Quelle que soit la manière, ça ne marche pas! (registre familier: quelle que soit la manière, ça marche pas!)

Je prononce «quoi que» et «quoique» exactement de la même façon, sauf étrangement si «quoique» est la fin laissée en suspens d’une réplique aux paroles de quelqu’un. Je prononce alors «quoique» en deux syllabes bien découpées, comme on pourrait imaginer «quoi que»:

- «Les deux tableaux dans la même pièces, ça ne peut pas aller!» «Ils vont mal ensemble, c’est vrai. Quooi-quee...»

Answer (score 1):

La pronociation devrait être différente. Je dis devrais car comme beaucoup de questions sur la prononciation, le français parlé et surtout les accents régionaux ne suit pas toujours la règle établie. Prononcer les deux de la même façon est donc tout à fait acceptable, comme le fait de faire la différence.

The pronunciation should be different. I say 'should' because as it is the case for many pronunciation questions, spoken French and more importantly the regional accents don't always follow the established rules. As such, pronouncing both in the same way is correct, as is pronouncing both differently.